# Gecko could not fill facebook post text area by Setattribute

Tags: vb.net, facebook, gecko, geckofx

I am dealing with a weird situation when I could not fill the facebook post area with text by using:

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsById("xc_message").SetAttribute("value", "hello world")
```

Meanwhile this works fine with VB.NET default Webbrowser and the below code works fine for facebook Login:

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void(document.forms[0].submit())")
```

I thought it should be similar however an error occurs when compiling:

[image: Compiling error image]

This is how it looks like, however I can not set a status message still.

[image: Element inspection Image]

Comment: `GetElementsById("xc_message")` returns an object for default browser, but not Gecko, is that correct? If it doesnt return the object you can't set the attribute and hence the null reference exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: _“Could you advise me?”_ - Yes: Any such attempts to automate login are against Facebook’s ToS, and if you get caught, you might end up getting your account blocked.

Comment: @CBroe Actually, it is not illegal. It is browser-based login method - the basic ^^.

Comment: @Codexer I tried with Webkit.Net also. The Id named "xc_message" does apply for Webkit (which is chrome browser based). And that id also exists for default VB.Net browser (which is IE based). So I think it is no problem with Gecko...But no work : (. The NullReferenceException you linked says a lot about everything so It is hard to solve the problem that way. Also, it runs well with the login part (no exception thrown) so I don't really understand...hmm

Comment: @AnhBa He didn't say it was illegal. He said it was against Facebook Terms of Service and most likely your account will be banned if you do it

Comment: @WizKid I actually run a facebook poster used VB.NET webbrowsers for months and my account is still working. It is the basic things like you open a webbrowser and enter login information...:D

Comment: Updated! Not yet answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while sorting out by googling. This is what works out:

```
Dim MyFBstatus As New GeckoTextAreaElement(GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")(0).DomObject) MyFBstatus.Value = "TESTING"
```